# Deployed Windows 10 Start Layout broken for new users

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1709

I have a Windows 10 1709 system I am working on imaging. During the setup, I created the Start Menu layout I wanted, exported the [StartLayout.XML](https://pastebin.com/iBA7Km1s) file to the local hard drive, then set the Group Policy object (User Configuration \ Admin Templates \ Start Menu \ Start Layout) to force it for users.

When I create a new user for testing, the tiles do not load correctly. If I log out and back in a second time, it works like a charm. Below is what it looks like on first log in for a new user:

[image]

I have deleted the test user, recreated, and the problem still exists. I followed the recommendations of using `DesktopApplicationID` entries as opposed to `DesktopApplicationFilePath` entries as recommended by [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/customize-and-export-start-layout).

Because I want this to work for many systems, and I'm without an Active Directory setup, I need this to work locally. With some of the computers, the user profiles are wiped after each log out, so it must apply as soon as the user logs in.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It is not adbormal to have to log into a domain and then log out of the domain to actually get and apply the appropriate group policies.  I have a domain, with zero clients, where that is required.  If you restart File Explorer does it make any difference?

Comment: Based on my test on local group policy, i have no this problem. If you were Domain group policy, as Ramhoud said, it's reasonable.

Comment: @KarenHu Are you doing it under User or Computer configuration? I can't seem to get it to work unless the user logs in twice

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, restarting Explorer works. It's a local group policy, with the `.xml` file on the local hard drive

Comment: @CanadianLuke - In theory, you could write a script, that forcefully closes and reopens the File Explorer process.  I suspect the policy in question is not being applied, and cannot be applied, the first time the profile is accessed.  I don't have another solution, we never figured out a different solution for our issue, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm going to try another method first. I've already wiped it 3 times trying to get this to work, so what's one more? Going to attempt to SysPrep it, with `CopyProfile` set to `true`

Comment: Version 1511 did not work either